# How to serve a video file like youtube?

Tags: node.js, angular6

when I serve a folder with some video file. Then I can access that files on the client after making a request. but seeking is not possible for that video because google chrome only fetches file upto 5mb.

nodejs:

```js
app.use('/static', express.static('files-folder'));
```

angular6+:

```js
http.get('/static/file-name')
```

html:

```html
<video [src]="static/file-name"></video>
```

Comment: The server needs to support range requests to get seeking in videos.

Comment: @DanD. how can I make the server to support range requests?

Comment: I don't have a solution for express. I attempted to do this with http and then edges made me fail back to an implementation written by someone else for my tiny attempt at a video server. It isn't hard to find such online by searching.

Comment: Do you have solutions in any language? If you have then please provide me so that i can take basic idea from that. @DanD.

Comment: I used https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813480/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-Node-js but on the same search node range request there is  https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static which look good and can be used with express. I should remark that I am still using node 0.12